# how can i make on alert button in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to have one button using an alert. However, two buttons (createTwoButtonAlert) work fine, but when I try to create one button (createOneButtonAlert) I get this error.

value for message cannot be cast from readablenativemap to string

this is my code

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';

    const Third = () => {
      const createOneButtonAlert = () =>
        Alert.alert('Alert Title', [
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed'), style: 'OK'},
        ]);

      const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
        Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'My Alert Msg', [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
        ]);



      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title={'1-Button Alert'} onPress={createOneButtonAlert} />
          <Button title={'2-Button Alert'} onPress={createTwoButtonAlert} />
        
        </View>
      );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    });

    export default Third;
```

how can i fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the problem

```
  Alert.alert('Alert Title','//Message required',[
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed'), style: 'OK'},
        ]);
```

If you see the call for the [alert](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#alert) the second parameter is the message which is a string

The way you have called, you pass an array instead of the expected string, the way to solve this would be to have an empty message or if you have a message better put that.

```
  Alert.alert('Alert Title','',[
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed'), style: 'OK'},
        ]);
```

This error 'cannot be cast from readablenativemap to string' occurs when the native code tries to use a string and some other type is passed (Specially in android)